How much does your R1 STEM department value teaching?
So I'm a tenure track prof in mathematics at an R1 university in the US. At the end of every year, every faculty gets an EOY review, where we are graded according to a number of criteria. Basically, there are various categories with various weightings. The heaviest weighting is for research, the lightest is for service. Our ultimate score has a variety of consequences, a big one being that it determines how big of a raise we get.
I'm curious how much your STEM department (math, physics, engineering, CS, chemistry...etc) at an R1 university in the US values teaching, measured in the above sense?
For me, the weighting works out to be around 21% for teaching (this includes teaching both undergrad and grad courses, but excludes mentoring of graduate students).
I'm curious how heavily your department weighs teaching in this sense? I understand that not every department works in the same way, so please provide some context with your answer.

Welcome to Academia.SE. I recommend rewriting this so it doesn't sound like a poll -- poll questions tend to be closed, but there is probably some aspect of this that is an interesting question.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not possible for it to have a single correct answer as written.

The 21% is a bit skewed if it doesn't include graduate student mentoring, but the number seems a bit low. I'd expect something closer to 30%, as in 60/30/10 for the emphasis. It's been a long while since I was at an R1 though and the one I was at had a special emphasis on teaching because of its (long) history. Some R1s have a very strong undergraduate program.
But if you add in the grad advising and such, you may get closer to 30%.
